# Autostart of a service when phone is powered on

Tags: java, android

I explain what I want my app does:

The user powers on the phone, my service starts and executes his code.
The problem is that at the moment the service doesn't start...I can't see logs or toast.

this is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="complic.bevoip">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_REBOOT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

...

```
        <service
            android:name=".Sip.SipService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"></service>

        <receiver android:name=".Sip.Receiver"
            android:process=":remote">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The broadcastReceiver

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("MIO", "abcde");
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        context.startService(new Intent(context, SipService.class));
    }
}
```

and the service

```
public class SipService extends Service {

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("BeVoip", "service partito");
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Starting background service when Android turns on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168869/starting-background-service-when-android-turns-on)

Comment: @crammeur that answer didn't helped me...

Comment: And this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974276/run-my-application-in-background-when-i-start-device-power-on-in-android

Comment: Do you receive the broadcast?

Comment: And this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056570/how-to-autostart-an-android-application

Comment: @YogeshM no, the problem is that but I don't understand where I'm going wrong

Comment: @crammeur yes, also that question didn't helped me, the code is exactly like my code is

Comment: This is the doc https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts

Answer (score 2):

Your `BroadcastReceiver` is not getting called because Apps targeting Android 7.0 **(API level 24)** and higher must register the following broadcasts with `registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter)`.

**Declaring a receiver in the manifest does not work**

You will have to register receiver dynamically in the following way.

```
    Receiver  myReceiver = new Receiver ();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED);
    intentFilter.addDataScheme("package");
    getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);
```

**About** `android:process=":remote"`

The `process` in which the broadcast receiver should run. All components of an application run in the default process created for the application. It has the same name as the **application package**.

If the name assigned to this attribute begins with a colon (':'), a new process, private to the application, is created when it's needed and the broadcast receiver runs in that process.

You can read about `receiver` attributes here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element

You can refer documentation of `BroadcastReceiver` here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts

Comment: Thanks but...this will work if the user opens the app once but I want the service starts as soon as the phone is powered on, or I'm saying something wrong?

Comment: Anyway, I put that piece of code in the main activity but it still doesn't work

Comment: In menifest file set the following attribute to receiver `android:exported="true" android:enabled="true"`